# Nested virtualization - running Hyper-V on Windows 10 guest under KVM with Linux Mint 18 as host

Tags: virtual-machine, linux-mint

I'm trying to do nested virtualization in different hypervisor environments.
Virtualbox does not support nested virtualization "out-of-the-box" according to my experience. VMWare Workstation Player 12 does, and I'm able to use Hyper-V on Windows 10 host. But under KVM (installed from the repository with virt-manager GUI) I'm not able to achieve the same goal. I get the following error from the Windows 10 guest: "Hyper-V cannot be installed. Virtualization support is disabled in firmware". I want to run Windows XP as guest OS in Windows 10 (Hyper-V) under Linux Mint 18 host.  :-)

Any suggestions on how I can solve this problem ?

Comment: Nested virtualization is a pretty steep topic, you might want to ask on specialized forums for people who do this kind of stuff.

Comment: OK. I was adviced to ask on this forum, but it might be the wrong one.
Do you know which forum I should use then ?

Answer (score 2):

You need the use the `kvm_intel nested=1` parameter when booting the kernel of your host OS (Mint Linux) to enable nested virtualization with KVM on an Intel-based system.

As Mint is based on the Debian distribution, the instructions [here](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Debian_8&p=kvm&f=8) will be useful to setup the system.

Comment: I have already checked that the kvm_intel nested=1 is present.
(And as I said earlier: VMWare Workstation Player 12 supports Hyper-V on Windows 10 guest... :-)

Comment: @toyman61 : Right, but I'd guess that the abstraction between operating systems will vary with the Hypervisor under use. Could you verify the requirements according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_compatibility)? It would also be good for comparison if you check the requirements on the VMWare setup and the KVM setup.

Comment: When I run "systeminfo.exe" on my Windows 10 host under kvm virtualization I get the following information:

Hyper-V Requirements:  A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.

It seems to me that Windows 10 has detected a hypervisor (KVM ?) and that's the reason why Hyper-V could not be started.

(Maybe the CPU-flag '-hypervisor' has something to do with this ?)

Comment: When creating the Guest OS using Hyper-V Manager, have you set `Use Dynamic Memory` to off? This seems to be required for a Nested Hyper-V host. In addition, try running the PowerShell script mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/user_guide/nesting#faq-and-troubleshooting).

Answer (score 2):

I have had a try at this a while back, with limited success.

Full discussion can be found here:
https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/qemu-discuss/2015-10/msg00039.html

The error you are getting is because Hyper-V wants MSR 0x3a return "5". This signifies that VT extensions are present and enabled in the BIOS. With a very small hack in vmx.c file, you can get Hyper-V to install: 
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106621

However, you cannot actually start Virtual Machines in the nested hypervisor.